# Removing .git from gitweb listings?

Tags: git

Is there a canonical way to remove the ".git" suffix from listings of `gitweb`? This is the only thing bothering me when viewing the repositories...

I could probably change this in the source, but upon updates, the modification would be overwritten. So I am looking for a more persistent solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was even easier than I suspected. The repository directory names were wrong. The script I used to create symbolical links automatically added a `.git` suffix for the directory that was not necessary. Fixing the script fixed my problem.

Sorry for the hassle.

Comment: I had similar problem - I populated my git root with symbolic links and found that you need to link to the .git subfolder.        ln -s ~/angular/angular-testing-course/.git ~/git-root/angular-testing-course

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that this is because your repositories are NOT bare repositories; that is, gitweb doesn't work correctly with [non-bare repositories](http://osdir.com/ml/git/2009-05/msg01245.html).  A good way to check is--the directory that gitweb is publishing; does it contain a bunch of directories with a .git directory?  The solution would be to use bare repositories (`git clone --bare`) instead.